# Will running the same R  script in a different terminal cause errors?

Tags: r, session, scripting

Currently, I create multiple copies of a script that each have a slightly different parameter values (3 different scripts). I run them from different folders. I'm wondering if I could just open three different terminals and run the same script. Of course, after starting each run at a particular parameter value, I would go back to the original script, change the parameter value, save the script and the run it again ...

I guess I'm not sure of all the steps that are preformed underneath the hood to run a script.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: running the same thing for different parameters can more easily be done using loops. Take a look for example at the functions in the plyr package. In this way you can even run them in parallel quite easily. I often do this using 6 cores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will have it's own memory and in no way overlap.

The only problem will be if both programs try to write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Large jobs may compete for RAM and provoke errors if they exceed resources on the machine.

Comment: and you should take care not to write or read to the same file on disk